# how to connect my ftp to Webstorm?

Tags: webstorm

I have an ftp where my files are store there,

I tried to find manuals that will explain how to connect the ftp to Webstorm,but with not much luck.

so I'm looking for referrals for this,

thanks.

Comment: Did you already read the [official documentation](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-a-project-from-downloaded-files.html)?

Comment: yes,I go to File->new project,but there is no option there called "Create New Project: Specify Remote Server" - where can I find this option?

Comment: Use **Create Project from Existing Files** on the Welcome Screen.

Comment: ok,found it,it's under File->new project from exiting files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**Create Project from Existing Files**](http://www.jetbrains.com/webstorm/webhelp/creating-a-project-from-downloaded-files.html) on the `Welcome Screen` or from the `File` menu.